# Bits of precision for IEE 754 floats(32 bits) between -1 and 1

Tags: ieee-754, floating-point-precision

Given a range of representable floating point numbers, how can I go about calculating the number of bits of precision that I will be able to store in a IEE 754 32-bit float in that range.

For instance, when performing a mathematical calculation where the result and numbers in question are expected to end up in a range of -1 to 1 or say 0 to 16, how would I go about calculating how many theoretical bits of precision exist within said range?

I realize that the values don't have even spacing and are more concentrated around 0, so this complicates the question.  In the end, I want to understand what values will not be rounded and how many significant digits I can expect within a range.  For instance, can I expect to store (without rounding), a value with accuracy down to 0.000001 in the range of -1 to 1?  How would I go about calculating this?

Comment: Have you read http://floating-point-gui.de/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do too much work to figure out your answer.  A 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point number has 23 bits of mantissa; counting the leading 1 gives 24 significant binary digits ([watch out for denorms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)).  By [doing some logarithms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+base+10+2%5E24) or looking it up in the [table on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_formats), you'll see that is about 7.22 decimal digits.

Let's take that fact and apply it to one of your examples.  All of the numbers you want (the ones with accuracy down to 0.000001) are therefore representable in a range -1 to 1 - those numbers all have 7 or fewer significant digits.

As to your other question about calculating the theoretical bits of precision in a range - it's the same everywhere.  Precision isn't related to magnitude - you get the same number of significant digits everywhere (again, watch out for denorms).  The representable numbers do start being more spaced apart in an absolute sense, as you mention.

If you want numbers with no rounding, you'll need to pick numbers that are representable exactly as a binary fraction multiplied a power of two.